# if condition not working properly inside a function python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

This is the following code.The test2 function doesnt get invoked why?
Even if i enter 1 the test2 fuction is not called

```
def test2():
    print("here i come")
def test1():
    x=input("hey ill take u to next fuction")
    if(x==1):
      test2()
test1()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=input("hey ill take u to next fuction")
```

`x` will be a string type, not an integer. You should change the `if` statement to compare the same types (either converting `x` to `int`, or `1` to `"1"`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing a string (your input) with 1 that is a integer.So you need to convert the input to `int` and then compare it.

Also as it can raise `ValueError` you can use a `try-except` to handle that :

```
def test1():
    x=input("hey ill take u to next fuction")
    try :
       if(int(x)==1):
          test2()
    except ValueError:
       print 'enter a valid number'
```